# data is not inserting

Tags: python, django

I am trying to insert data using django forms API but it not working whenever I try to insert data it doesn't insert into the database

Here is my VIews.py

```
def create_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            p_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            p_cat = form.cleaned_data['category']
            p_brand = form.cleaned_data['brand']
            p_price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            p_image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            p_desc = form.cleaned_data['desc']

            save_product = Product(name=p_name, category=p_cat, brand=p_brand, price=p_price, image=p_image, desc=p_desc)
            save_product.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed To Insert Data!")
    else:
        form = CreateProductForm()
    params = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'adminpanel/createPro.html', params)
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<form class="col-sm-9 m-6" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product">
</form>
```

Here is my forms.py

from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from .models import Product

```
class CreateProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'brand', 'image', 'price', 'desc']
```

Here is my Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='UNCATEGORIZED')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='NoBrand')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    price = models.FloatField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

Comment: please debug and specify the exact error

Comment: i am not getting any error @SivaSankar

Comment: I am assuming DEBUG=False in your settings.py . If that is the case in the terminal (from where Django was launched) error messages should still be printed. Please check the console/terminal.

Comment: Do you have any form errors? In the models you have an `ImageField` that is required, but you didn't include `request.FILES` in the `CreateProductForm()` and then later if form is valid, all you need to do is call `form.save()`. Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_product(request):
    form = CreateProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed To Insert Data!")

    params = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'adminpanel/createPro.html', params)
```